# Performance issues with glue job while reading huge data from redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to run a query to read data from a Redshift table through an AWS Glue job.

Now, when it reads the data from the Redshift table, it creates a dataframe with only 1 partition and it takes a lot of time to read the data (Data reading from the Redshift table is done using a complex query that has multiple joins).

```py
df = spark.read \
          .format("jdbc") \
          .option("url", url) \
          .option("query", query) \
          .option("numPartitions", 10) \
          .option("fetchsize", "10000") \
          .option("batchsize", "10000") \
          .load()
```

I used `numPartitions` as `10` and it is still reading the whole data in one partition. Not sure why it is not impacting to create `10` partitions while reading.

Can anyone help me understand why `.option("numPartitions", 10)` is not effective and how can we implement parallelism while reading data from Redshift to improve the performance of JDBC read?

Also is this the best approach to read data from Redshift by passing complex queries to the `spark.read.jdbc()` method?

Appreciate any help on this.

**Update:**

I tried with the suggestion given by Bogdan but still, it is not giving any improvement.

[image]

It's always running with 2 executors(1 is for the driver and 1 is the worker node). How do we improve read parallel? I tried different options as follows and I don't see any improvement. I am looking for reading with 10 to 20 executors and any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```py
DF_options  = {
                "connectionName": connection,
                "url": url,
                "sampleQuery": query,
                "user": user,
                "password": pwd,
                "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://bucket/temp/",
                "hashfield": "location",
                "hashexpression": "id",
                "hashpartitions": "5"

        }

DF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
                 connection_type="redshift", 
                 connection_options=DF_options,
                 transformation_ctx="DF"
     )
```

Thanks,

Bab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read a JDBC source in parallel you need to define `partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound`, check [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option). Spark will use this configuration to split the original query in `numPartitions` queries.

The query will be very roughly splitted like below and Spark can send the separated queries in parallel, if you have enough executors/cores/slots.

```sql
-- Original query:
SELECT *
FROM my_table

-- Queries with:
--  partitionColumn = 'my_date'
--  lowerBound = '2021-01-01'
--  upperBound = '2021-01-02'
--  numPartitions = 3

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_date < '2021-01-01'

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_date >= '2021-01-01'
  AND my_date < '2021-01-02'

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_date >= '2021-01-02'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response boyangeor. can we pass complex query with where conditions or it needs to be always simple select * from table? because it is not supporting query with datable option.

Comment: Instead of `query` you can use the `dbtable` option which can be a custom query (from [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option) "anything that is valid in a FROM clause of a SQL query"). The additional filters for partitions will be added to the query.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me very well on redshift queries :

```
print(f"Executing SQL query = {sql_query}")

# Script generated for node Amazon Redshift
AmazonRedshift_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options={
        "sampleQuery": sql_query ,
        "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://aws-glue-assets-***/temporary/",
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "connectionName": "your-connection-name",
        "aws_iam_user": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/yourGlueRole"
    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonRedshift_node1",)

print("Size of DynamicFrame: {}".format(AmazonRedshift_node1.toDF().count()))
```

Comment: Thank you Bogdan for your quick response. I tried your suggestion above and still it is not improved. Is this created multiple partitions or single partition after reading data?